# How to unmount CD drive

Tags: drive, cd, unmount

I am returning to Ubuntu after some time so I am a bit rusty.  My machine is running 16.04 LTS  and I want to upgrade to the current 18.04.  I have downloaded this and want to transfer it to a CD-R so that I can boot from that but I get an error message saying that the drive is already mounted.  They problem is that I cannot remember how to un-mount it or find the instructions in the built-in help.

I could, I suppose, upgrade directly from the downloaded copy on the HD but I cannot remember how to do that either.

Thank you.

Comment: Current versions of Ubuntu is too big for a CD. You need a DVD. To transfer the ISO file for Ubuntu 18.04 to either a blank USB flash drive or a blank DVD use the app **Startup Disk Creator** in the Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

For the first drive use:

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sr0
```

For the second drive:

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sr1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather do it the graphical way, just launch Disks from the launcher. Click on your CD drive, and you'll see a square under where the partitions are. Click it, and you're done!

[image: Easy as pie.]